# Dynamically search SQLite database for product name which is entered by the final user character by character

Tags: android

In an Android application,

There is a SQLite database with 10000 records of different products
I need to use an Edittext for the user to be able to search among the products by name

When the user types a character, the search result with the newly added character shall be appeared

There are some problem:

1 - the user shall not sense any delay when typing the new characters
In other word, when one character is added, it takes a time to search the database and if this time is not yet elapsed then the user may have a problem to type a new character

2 - If just one character is there, there would be so many search result and if I limit the search result items to 20 you say, then all possible products would not be appeared and the user may not like it

How can I handle these issues, is there any standard on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you do a database search in UI Thread, the processing speed decreases.
You can also process the database in the background.
To do this, simply create a sub Thread and include the database search operation in that thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){  //search in Database}
)};
thread.start();
```